# Display php selected JSON data with angular ngRepeat

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to display data which I select from a mySQL database using PHP. The data should be shown in angular variables.
I can see the JSON when clicking a button I installed. But the data will not show up in the angular variables. So I think the problem is the communication between php and angular on the way back from php to angular.

Here are the files I use. Where do i have to make changes to get what I want?

Thank you!

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
    <title>nutrimeal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-sm-10 content">
        <h1>M E A L S</h1>
        <form action="./php/meal_select.php" method="post">
          <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="display meals"/>
        </form>
        <div ng-controller = "MealsController as meals">
          <p>The meals should be shown underneath</p>
          <div ng-repeat="meal in meals">
            {{ meal.name }}
            {{ meal.daytime }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- Javascript references -->
    <script src="./js/vendors/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/vendors/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### app.js

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])

// MealsController
app.controller('MealsController', [ '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.displayData = function(){
    var meals =  $http.get('./backend/meal_select.php')
//   .then(function (response) {$scope.accounts = response.data.records;} );
    .then(function (data) {
      $scope.meals = data });
};
$scope.displayData()
}]);
```

### meal_select.php

```
<?php

// connection settings
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "qwertz";
$dbname = "example_nutrition";

// create connection to db
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// set SQL command
$sql = "SELECT meal_id, name, daytime FROM meal";

// query db
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// show results
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $r=array()
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $r=[] = $row;
//simple output
    // echo " Account Name: " . $row["account_name"].
      //    " Balance: " . $row["initial_balance"].
        //  " Currency: " . $row["currency"].  "<br>";

// output as JSON
     //$json_array = json_encode($row);
     $json_array = json_encode($r);
     header('Content-type: application/json');
     echo $json_array;
  }
}
// if nothing was found
          else {
            echo "0 results";
}

// close connection to db
$conn->close();
?>
```

### JSON displayed after clicking the button

> {"meal_id":"1","name":"cheeseburger","daytime":"lunch"}
>       {"meal_id":"2","name":"chili con carne","daytime":"lunch"}

Comment: your json file are object ?

Comment: What does that mean? Where can I look that up?

Comment: In app.js I changed "$scope.accounts to "$scope.meals" and "var accounts" to "var meals"

Comment: following my code in edit

Comment: you dont need use `var`

Comment: Now the variables are shown where I want to see the values:
{{ meal.name }} {{ meal.daytime }}
I added "$scope.displayData()" and changed .success to .then

Comment: problem have solved ? If not you could see the code in php of me . And if it solved . Please accept my answer

Comment: I did change the php to the above but it's still not working.

Comment: try remove  `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: I'm not familar with php but you can try my code in edit2

Comment: well, a lot of guessing right now. I tried both an neither works

Reduce my problem to: How do I get data in my html from a mysql database using angular and php.

Comment: check my edited answer

Comment: Mmh, can you tell something more about what you did. I already tried different guesses. Otherwise that feels like shooting blindfolded on cans. I'm looking for a well-founded answer.

Comment: I uploaded the files to github: https://github.com/ChristianSchmitz81/example

Comment: which part do not you understand ?

Comment: I try explain in edit . you can check this

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

PHP

```
$row = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ...";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result){
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Angular

```
  $scope.showData = function(){
    $http.get('data.php').then(function(response){
                $scope.data = response.data;
   }
   $scope.showData();
```

});

HTML

```
<ul ng-repeat ="d in data">
<li> {{d.name}}</li>
<li> {{d.age}}</li>
 ...
</ul>
```

I think this code above is simple and you can understand , but I will explain a bit. In angular we have  two options for ng-repeat:

1.Object

2.Array

If you are using an `object` inside `ng-repeat` then you need to use it something like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">  
   <li> {{ key }} : {{ value }}</li>  
</ul>
```

And if you are using `array` inside `ng-repeat` then you can do like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="d in data">  
    <li>{{ d.name}}</li> 
    <li>{{ d.age}}</li> 
</ul>
```

Now understand what is happening here, you are getting a response from server which is an object  and trying to print it like an array and it reason why it not work (and you forget invoked function). This is why I talk you add two line code in php

```
$row = array();
$rows[] = $r;
```

If you dont have two line , your json is object and you cant print it like array . But if you have two line ,  your json is array and you can print it like array

Comment: I copied files from the tutorial which you can find under the following link. And there is the same problem - no data will be shown. I thought about a browser problem, but chrome and safari had the same problem. Do you have any idea?
http://www.webslesson.info/2016/09/angularjs-tutorial-with-php-fetch-select-data-from-mysql-database.html

Comment: This tutorial is out of date . In show data you should change to    `.then(function(data){  
                $scope.names = data.data;` . And can you post full your json file

Comment: @Krs81 you can following this code in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820731/use-http-angularjs-callback-properly-with-php/43820911?noredirect=1#comment74680782_43820911 . It delete but same with insert . You just change code in php , insert directly instead use switch case