# Use $http angularjs Callback properly with php?

Tags: php, angularjs

So I am trying to send an $http angularjs request to php but the it will trigger `successCallback` (so does that mean that my request is successful?) but when I checked my database nothing happened and my data is still there. I know I'm missing something in here. please help.

**Controller** (which calls the `checkPollCodeIfAvail` function)

```
pollFactory.checkPollCodeIfAvail('qwe123').then(function successCallback(response){
    console.log('success');
}, function errorCallback(response){
    console.log('fail');
});
```

**Factory:**

```
factory.checkPollCodeIfAvail = function(x){
    code = x;
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            'action' : 'checkPollCode',
            'pollCode' : code
        },
        url: 'http://localhost/poll/api.php'
    });
};

return factory;
```

**api.php**

```
if(empty($_POST['action'])){
    return;
}

if(($_POST['action']) == "checkPollCode"){
    $checkPollCode = $_POST['pollCode'];
}

switch ($_POST['action']) {
    case 'checkPollCode':
        $sql = "DELETE FROM polls WHERE pollCode = :pollcode";
        $stmt = $db_con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":pollcode", $checkPollCode);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "error";
        }
        break;
}
```

Thank you for anyone that can help me.

Comment: method of you is `GET` but in php is `POST`

Comment: Thanks for the response but I tried changing it to `POST` but it still won't work.

Comment: why you use switch case in php . try delete directly and remove `successCallback` in angular

Comment: I `used` switch since I will be having a few actions in my php file. Why do I have to remove `successCallback`?

Comment: you dont need it , and in angular you should transform data before send it . Let me try create answer

Comment: what is the status code you get in your console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular try add this

```
 return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            'action' : 'checkPollCode',
            'pollCode' : code
        },
        url: 'http://localhost/poll/api.php'
        transformRequest:function(obj) {
                var str=[];
            for(var p in obj){
    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]))
                                }
                                return str.join("&");
                            },
                headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function(response){
    console.log('success');
}
```

Defaut type header of angular is application/json , and if you dont change header , you should decode input in php . I'm  not familar with php and I change to form-urlencoded .

For application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the body of the HTTP message sent to the server is essentially one giant query string -- name/value pairs are separated by the ampersand (&), and names are separated from values by the equals symbol (=). An example of this would be:

```
MyVariableOne=ValueOne&MyVariableTwo=ValueTwo
```

And this code

```
transformRequest:function(obj) {
                    var str=[];
                for(var p in obj){
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]))
                                    }
                                    return str.join("&");
                                }
```

before send data to server , you loop though data and transform it to `x-www-form-urlencoded` .

Comment: This works thank you but I'm a newbie in angularjs and I don't really understand this code and why do I need to do this. Can you explain what's happening here?

Comment: @CityDove I edited answer and try explain  . My english not good so it's hard for me to explain clearly

Comment: @ThanTung I see. Thank you! I have another question. Is the `response` in the `.then(function(response)` the echoed "success" in my php?

Comment: @CityDove what do you mean ? If you mean is display echo"success" in php you should create array in php and put message echo and encode it .

Comment: Like this : `$ar = array()  ar['message'] ='success'   json_encode($ar);` And in angular `$scope.sucess = response.data.message;`

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you very much for your time and help! You helped me understand angularjs more. Thanks!

Comment: I’m so glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some pbm in Http

Try this Code :

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('action', "checkPollCode");
fd.append('pollCode', code);

$http.post("http://localhost/poll/api.php", fd, {
transformRequest: angular.identity,
headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, conf) {
    //Evrytheng OK
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("You have some error");
});
```

Don't forget adding $Http in your controller:

```
app.controller('YourController', ['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http){...
```